# Can I also know the average session time of the user which a user spends on my Nokia (Symbian) app per day?

Tags: symbian

How to know the average session time of the user which a user spends on my app?

Can I also know the average session time of the user which a user spends on my app per day?

I also want to know the number of clicks on the player on my Live TV App?

Please help me with these reports analysis methods

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As the tags only indicate that this is Symbian app. Then, as you can not get process starting events or any other nice events from external apps, you would actually need to build the statistics into your own app. F.ex. In the application class, mark down the time when it gets constructed, and in the destruct or just save the usage time.,

And for other statistics, you also would need to gather them inside your wpp, with your own logic.

And then, you also would need to implement custom logic for uploading the data to your server..